# Load javascript second time viewing a single post (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function

I am trying to load a piece of javascript **the second time** a user views a single post on my WP website.

I already found a few pieces of code that will probably do the trick after some tweaking..

```
function is_first_time() {
if (isset($_COOKIE['_wp_first_time']) || is_user_logged_in()) {
    return false;
} else {
    // expires in 30 days.
    setcookie('_wp_first_time', 1, time() + (WEEK_IN_SECONDS * 4), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);

    return true;
}
```

} 
add_action( 'init', 'is_first_time');

```
<?php if ( is_single() ){ ?>
```

Comment: Look for cookie, if not there, place cookie. If cookie *is* there, show 2nd time viewing option.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I got the cookie construction set up but now javascript doesnt seem to load as the "second time viewing uption"..

Comment: What is the javascript you're trying to execute? What I see is PHP so any content/javascript that you would want to load *only* if the cookie is found would have to be within either the (cookie is true) statement or the (cookie not set) else {} statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_first_time() {
  if (isset($_COOKIE['_wp_first_time']) || is_user_logged_in()) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    // expires in 30 days.
    setcookie('_wp_first_time', 1, time() + (WEEK_IN_SECONDS * 4), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Your "if 2nd time or more" scripting:

```
if(is_first_time()===0){
  //do things for 2+ view, i.e. <script></script>, etc.
}
```